# Every time I try to install matplotlib using pip install matplotlib it keep saying that it has failed to build a wheel for numpy

Tags: python, pip, python-module

Every time I try to install matplotlib using pip install matplotlib it keep saying that it has failed to build a wheel for numpy

```
 **Failed building wheel for numpy**
  Running setup.py clean for numpy
Failed to build numpy
Installing collected packages: numpy, matplotlib
  Running setup.py install for numpy ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\carlos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7ydkfijt\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-v9pdoykz-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    Running from numpy source directory.
    blas_opt_info:
    blas_mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    openblas_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_blas_info:
      libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_blas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ydkfijt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1651: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_info:
      libraries blas not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ydkfijt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1660: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
        the BLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    blas_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ydkfijt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1663: UserWarning:
        Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
        the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(BlasSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
    F2PY Version 2
    lapack_opt_info:
    openblas_lapack_info:
      libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    lapack_mkl_info:
    mkl_info:
      libraries mkl,vml,guide not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_3_10_info:
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_threads_info:
    Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    atlas_info:
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
      libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
      libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\libs
    <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ydkfijt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1552: UserWarning:
        Atlas (http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [atlas]) or by setting
        the ATLAS environment variable.
      warnings.warn(AtlasNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_info:
      libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\lib', 'C:\\', 'c:\\users\\carlos\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python35-32\\libs']
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ydkfijt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1563: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
        Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
        the LAPACK environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackNotFoundError.__doc__)
    lapack_src_info:
      NOT AVAILABLE

    C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ydkfijt\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1566: UserWarning:
        Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
        Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
        numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
        the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
      warnings.warn(LapackSrcNotFoundError.__doc__)
      NOT AVAILABLE

    c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\distutils\dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    running install
    running build
    running config_cc
    unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
    running config_fc
    unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
    running build_src
    build_src
    building py_modules sources
    building library "npymath" sources
    No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
    error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat


    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\carlos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\carlos\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-7ydkfijt\\numpy\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-v9pdoykz-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\carlos\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-7ydkfijt\numpy
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat)

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to install [anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), which already includes numpy.

Or you can download precompiled [numpy for windows](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/).

There's also an answer about missing vcvarsall.bat already on stack overflow, [error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat) if that interests you.